# Linux: warning implicit declaration of function of system call

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

So I am writing a new system call and adding it to the kernel of Linux which works when I explicitly call it through the system call number: `syscall(335, pid);`
but gives an warning: implicit declaration of function of the system call when using its general name: `s_call(pid)`. I can't figure out why its not finding it.

-test file is already in the kernel
-the system call is already defined in sys.c     `SYSCALL_DEFINE1(s_call, int, who)`
-has an asmlinkage in syscalls.h      `asmlinkage long sys_s_call(int pid);`
-in the syscall_64.tbl as

```
335 64  s_call      __x64_sys_s_call
```

-headers being used in the test file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you need to write a wrapper for the system call in your program. Wrapper functions don't just magically show up in user-space when you write system calls:

```
long s_call(int pid)
{
    return syscall(335, pid);
}
```

If you have a header file with your syscall's number, you don't have to use a magic number:

```
long s_call(int pid)
{
    return syscall(__NR_s_call, pid);
}
```

Also, you should be using `pid_t` instead of `int`.

Comment: Where would you write the wrapper for the system call in the kernel?

Comment: @arkay Not in the kernel, in your application.